# Best way to convert a string to milliseconds in Python

Tags: python, datetime

To convert the amount of milliseconds represented by a string I created the following function:

```
time_str = '1:16.435'

def milli(time_str):
  m, s = time_str.split(':')
  return int(int(m) * 60000 + float(s) * 1000)

milli(time_str)
```

But I'm wondering if there is a native Python function to do this directly.

Comment: If your function works then there is little reason I see to replace it with another package. Is there something out there that does this? Probably. However what advantages would using that give over using your own function? :)

Comment: Good answer @Mitchnoff. Just knowledge curiosity. ;-) Maybe there's a much more efficient and pythonic way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to stick to the std library, then one could use time.strptime() and then find the delta from t=0 to that time. However, this is a clunky solution. Honestly the function you have already is good. It would also be fairly easy to extend to strings with a days and years position, but as you're dealing with milliseconds that probably isn't something you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make it longer and more complicated with `datetime`:

```
import datetime
dateobj=datetime.datetime.strptime("1:16.435","%M:%S.%f")
timeobj=dateobj.time()
print(timeobj.minute*60000+timeobj.second*1000+timeobj.microsecond/1000)
```

> ```
> 76435.0
> ```

Now you have 2 additions, 2 multiplications, and even a division. And the bonus points for loading a package, of course. I like your original code more.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for functions to do this for you, you can take advantage of `TimeDelta` object which has `.total_seconds()`. This way you don't have to do that calculation. Just create your `datetime` objects then subtract them:

```py
from datetime import datetime

datetime_obj = datetime.strptime("1:16.435", "%M:%S.%f")
start_time = datetime(1900, 1, 1)
print((datetime_obj - start_time).total_seconds() * 1000)
```

output:

```
76435.0
```

The reason for choosing `datetime(1900, 1, 1)` is that when you use `strptime` with that format it fills the rest to make this form: `1900-01-01 00:01:16.435000`.

---

If your string changes to have *Hour* for example, you just need to change your format and it works as expected. No need to change your formula and add another calculation:

```py
datetime.strptime("1:1:16.435", "%H:%M:%S.%f")
start_time = datetime(1900, 1, 1)
print((datetime_obj - start_time).total_seconds() * 1000)
```