# Value of column based on value of other column using pandas.apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

| index | season | round | number | driverId | position | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1996 | 1 | 1 | villeneuve | 1 | 1:43.702 |
| 1 | 1996 | 1 | 1 | damon_hill | 2 | 1:44.243 |
| 2 | 1996 | 1 | 1 | irvine | 3 | 1:44.981 |

with `df_laps[['ms']] = 0` I can create a new column **ms** with all rows containing value = 0.

| index | season | round | number | driverId | position | time | ms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1996 | 1 | 1 | villeneuve | 1 | 1:43.702 | 0 |
| 1 | 1996 | 1 | 1 | damon_hill | 2 | 1:44.243 | 0 |
| 2 | 1996 | 1 | 1 | irvine | 3 | 1:44.981 | 0 |

Nevertheless the value of **ms** must be related to the value of **time**. So I tried with the following `df_laps[['ms']] = df_laps.loc[0, ['time']].apply(milli)`, but all values applied the value of the first row (1:43.702 = 103702) as I use 0 for the first loc parameter. How could I iterate this value so that the results would be: 103702, 104243, 104981 respectively?

By the way, milli is a function that converts the **str time** into **int ms**. You can see more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73311370/best-way-to-convert-a-string-to-milliseconds-in-python).

| index | season | round | number | driverId | position | time | ms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1996 | 1 | 1 | villeneuve | 1 | 1:43.702 | 103702 |
| 1 | 1996 | 1 | 1 | damon_hill | 2 | 1:44.243 | 103702 |
| 2 | 1996 | 1 | 1 | irvine | 3 | 1:44.981 | 103702 |

In other words, what should I do to have the value in **ms** related to the value in **time** of the same row? Based on https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html I've tried also `.apply(milli, axis = 1)`, but then I receive following error: "milli() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df_laps['ms'] = df_laps['time'].apply(milli)
```

or:

```
df_laps['ms'] = df_laps['time'].apply(lambda x:milli(x))
```

Comment: Hi @gtomer, you mean df_laps['ms'] = df_laps['time'].apply(milli) instead, don't you? With time it worked. Thanks! (I'm unable to edit your answer)